# Pynput cant seem to get my code to see it

Tags: python-3.x, pynput

when i try running it on idle i get this

```
File "C:\Users\ninja\OneDrive\Desktop\auto-clicker.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'
```

I installed pynput on my cmd used pip3 and pip
I am using python3

Answer (score 0):

Where you have Python installed, make sure that the `pynput.py` file is under `./python3/Lib/site-packages/pynput`. Or, when you install it, have it in the same directory as the python executable files are in, and it will automatically go into this folder.

Also, make sure you don't have another file called `pynput.py` in the same directory as the program that is being run, as it will use that instead of the module you want.

I noticed that you are using OneDrive. Make sure that you have pynput installed on the device you are currently using, abiding to the first solution.

These have solved my previous module errors, so I hope they work for you.